# How to connect to MongoDB with constructed string?

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I have successully connect to MongoDB with the following code:

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, { useNewUrlParser: true })
.then(() => console.log(`Connected to ${process.env.DB_NAME}`));

mongoose.connection.on('error', err => {
console.log(`${err.message}`);
});
```

It works fine When `MONGO_URI` (defined in an attached file) is as follows:

```
MONGO_URI=mongodb+srv://someServer:<YourPassword>@cluster01234-d5678obt.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true'
```

However, I want the ease to change `YourPassword` and `MONGO_URI` to be dynamically constructed.  Thus, I change it to:

```
PASSWORD=somePassword
MONGO_URI='mongodb+srv://someServer:' + PASSWORD + '@cluster01234-d5678obt.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true'
```

And it throws me this error:

```
Cannot read property 'split' of null
```

How can I do it without running into this error?  Many thanks.

Comment: Well where are you splitting the string in your code? Please post *all relevant code*.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so this is the answer to it:

```
const PASSWORD=somePassword
MONGO_URI='mongodb+srv://someServer:' + PASSWORD + '@cluster01234-d5678obt.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true'
```

Comment: Actually, scratch that.  Must use hard string or will fail to connect.  This error will be thrown:

    Cannot read property 'split' of null

Must use one single connection string to connect to database properly.